# Amenable groups acting on the real line, that are not subexponentially-amenable

Tags: gr.group-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, amenability, ordered-groups

In the literature, there are several examples of solvable groups acting faithfully by order-preserving homeomorphisms of the real line. There are also examples of groups of intermediate growth with such actions (see for instance A. Navas *"Groups of circle diffeomorphisms"* [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0607481)). So my question is:

> Is there an example of an amenable but not subexponentially-amenable group acting faithfully by order-preserving homeomorphisms of the real line?

Where by the class of *subexponentially-amenable groups* I mean a the smallest class containing the groups of subexponential growth and which is closed under taking subgroups, quotients, extensions and direct limits.

I should also point out that, for countable groups, having a faithful action by order preserving homeomorphisms of the real line is equivalent to admitting a left-ordering, that is a total ordering which is invariant under left multiplication. So an equivalent question is

> Is there an example of a left-orderable amenable group that is not subexponentially-amenable?

Comment: Does the Grigorchuk group act in this way?

Comment: Finitely generated elementary amenable groups cannot have intermediate growth (C. Chow, 1980). Hence, examples of intermediate growth answer your question.

Comment: You also have to clarify what you mean by "non-elementary amenable", since it can be interpreted as either (1) amenable group which is not elementary amenable, (2) group which fails to be elementary amenable. In the latter case, examples are much easier since one can easily construct a free nonabelian group of diffeomorphisms of line preserving orientation.

Comment: @Noah The Grigorchuk group have torsion, so it does not acts by order preserving homeos of the real line. However, there is a variation of it, from Grigorchuk and Maki, which acts on the real line (and still have intermediate growth).

Comment: @Misha I have edited the Question, thank you both!

Comment: Is this question answered for the Basilica group?

Comment: @MustafaGokhanBenli Sure!, Basilica is one instance of an amenable non-subexponentially-amenable group.

Comment: @CristobalRivas So is Basilica left orderable or not?

Comment: I don not know!

Comment: It hasn't been answered yet, but if Thompson's group $F$ is amenable, then it answers the question. In particular, one shouldn't be able to prove the answer is no (unless solving a well-known hard question).